# PHPunit mocking call mocked method in same mocked object

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, dependencies, phpunit

I have question about mocking object...

I have class "Example", and I need to test callMethod()

```
public function callMethod() {
  $item = 0;
  foreach($this->returnSomething() as $list) {
    $item = $item + $list->sum;
  }
  return $item; 
}
```

I have test method where I mock "returnSomething" to return me some data, but problem is than It doesn't call mocked method.

This is part of test method where im mocking "returnSomething" and call "callMethod".

```
$mock = mock("Example");
$mock->shouldReceive("returnSomething")->once()->withNoArgs()->andReturn($returnItems);
$result = $mock->callMethod();
```

Is it possible to call mocked "returnSomething" without changing "callMethod" definition and forwarding $mock object into that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to mock only specified method.

**Examples:**

Mockery:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock("Example[returnSomething]");
```

PHPUnit:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Example', array('returnSomething'));
```

or

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Example')
    ->setMethods(array('returnSomething'))
    ->getMock();
```

With above cases a framework will mock only `returnSomething` method and leave the rest methods as in original object.

Comment: I believe PHPUnit allows you to mock ALL the functions by not setting the array('returnSomething') but leave it blank to have all functions mocked.  However, you will only receive the one return value then.

Comment: I understood the question in that way: how to mock only certain method from a class, and leave rest methods as they are in original class. I see my expression "you can mock only specified method" is confusing, the sense what I meant was: "It is possible to mock only specified method". I will fix the answer, thanks

Comment: Be careful with usage of `setMethods()`. This method is deprecated since PHPUnit 8 and will be deleted in PHPUnit 10. Use `onlyMethods()` instead. An example can be found in the answers here.

Answer (score 4):

I am writing this because today I found the answer here, but setMethods() is deprecated (phpunit 8.5), the alternative is onlyMethods() and it can be used as follows:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Example::class)
             ->onlyMethods(['yourOnlyMethodYouWantToMock'])
             ->getMock();

$mock->method('yourOnlyMethodYouWantToMock')
            ->withAnyParameters()
            ->willReturn($yourReturnValue);
```